# How to use the PDFBox PDInlineImage

Tags: java, pdfbox

I would like to add an image to the existing PDF document using the `PDInlineImage`, but the resulting image is not displayed,My code is the following:

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, document.getPage(0), PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\1.png"));

COSDictionary cosDictionary = new COSDictionary();

PDInlineImage inlineImage = new PDInlineImage(cosDictionary,bytes,document.getPage(0).getResources());
inlineImage.setStencil(true);
inlineImage.setWidth(100);
inlineImage.setHeight(100);
inlineImage.setInterpolate(true);
contentStream.drawImage(inlineImage, 300,90);
contentStream.close();
```

Comment: Take a look at `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDInlineImageTest.testInlineImage()` - you will see that you need preprocessed image data.

Comment: Another way (I haven't tested this yet) would be to create a normal image first with `LosslessFactory`, then to get the raw stream as data[] parameter and of course use the filter too. @JIAN are you sure you NEED an inline image, i.e. you don't want to use a classic image?

Comment: Btw per PDF specification, inline images should not be larger than 4 KB.